# Hide Jetty Server header

Tags: java, jetty-9

I have hidden apache server details by adding  the below line at the end of apache configurations file

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

I wish to hide the jetty header in the curl and in browser . 
Header to get hidden :
`Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)`

I have downloaded the jetty-9.4.8 and used the below command to deploy the java war file in the server .

`nohup java  -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000 -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=epoch_temp_dir -jar jetty-runner-9.4.8.v20171121.jar --log yyyy_mm_dd-integration-request.log --out yyyy_mm_dd-testing-output.log --port 9010 --path /testing testing.war >> testing.log 2>&1 &`

Can any one help me on this out ?

Comment: I guess adding `-Djetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=false` will do the trick.

Comment: added that . still i can see the server version in the `curl -v ` command